# Linq grouping on view table

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I have a view in SQL server that is an aggregation of a many to many.  So the data returned is something like this:

```
User1 : Data1
User1 : Data2
User1 : Data3
User2 : Data1
User2 : Data2
```

etc.

Normally if I'm using LINQ with Entity Framework I use the navigation properties and get nested lists.  So I can loop through Users and a nested loop through the data from the join table.

With a flat view, it is just one big list.  I'm trying to group on the user so I can use the same foreach loops to display data.

E.g.,

```
User1 - Data1, Data2, Data3
User2 - Data1, Data2, Data3
```

Is there a way to create the grouping this way based on a single table (view)

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it.

```
var q = from x in db.tbl
        group x by x.User into g
        select new
        {
           User = g.Key,
           Data = g.Select(y => y.Data)
        };
```

Comment: What type is q expected to be?  I'm trying to return this as a model to a razor view in MVC3.

Comment: So it looks like this works well.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160420/how-do-i-group-data-in-an-asp-net-mvc-view

Comment: Right now it is returning an anonymous type but you can create any type you like.