# Better way to generate html in mvc4

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

Right now I have in my `Mvc4` project a `.cs` class named `HTMLcreator` in my `App_Code` folder, which makes `html` for me to render in my views.

This I've heard is not the best way, and it's tiring to update the `html` elements in the `.cs` file.

What whould be a better way to create dynamic html for the view to use?

---

HTMLcreator.cs:

```
public static string methodOne()
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        List<Subjects> subjects = Subjects.GetAll(); // Gets a some objects

        foreach (Subjects s in subjects)
        {
            result.Append("<p>" + s.name + "</p>");

            if(s.hasChild)
            {
                result.Append(methodTwo(Subjects.GetChild(s)));
            }
        }
        return Convert.ToString(result);
    }

public static string methodTwo(Subjects s)
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        result.Append("<p>" + s.name + "</p>");

        if(s.hasChild)
        {
            result.Append(methodTwo(Subjects.GetChild(s)));
        }
        return Convert.ToString(result);
    }
```

---

The View calls the method with a `@Html.Raw` method.

Comment: How about using Views in the way they were intended?  Views allow scaffolding of the web page, and give you the ability to inject values into them.  You seem to be taking the approach of generating the *entire* web page and injecting that.  In ASP.NET MVC 4 they even give you a nice syntax called Razor for accomplishing this.  Why reinvent an already nice wheel?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. Do you not use html views?

Comment: Why `Convert.ToString(result)` instead of `result.ToString()`?

Comment: @asawyer & Robert Harvey: I am using views. I just have some code where I need to loop thru a list of objects, and generate some html based on that. Can I do something similar only using views? ´cause that would be a solution  ^^

Comment: @MichaelTotKorsgaard That sounds exactly like what I would do with an Edit/Display template partial view.

Comment: @MichaelTotKorsgaard: You can create loops in the view, directly.  See here for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1160420/102937

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I know. But what about a loop calling itself, like my code does?

Comment: That's just ordinary recursion.  You can do the same in View code, with a bit of ingenuity.  However, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/942489.

Comment: See also http://weblogs.asp.net/raduenuca/archive/2011/04/24/asp-net-mvc-displaying-a-tree-view-using-a-recursive-declarative-helper-and-jquery.aspx

Comment: And http://weblogs.asp.net/jigardesai/archive/2008/02/04/display-hierarchical-data-in-asp-net-mvc-framework.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you actually need here is a `helper`:

```
@helper methodOne(Subjects subjects)
{
    foreach (var subject in subjects)
    {
        <p>@subject.name</p>

        if (subject.hasChild)
            @methodOne(Subjects.GetChild(subject))
    }
}
```

Then use it somewhere in your View:

```
<div>
      @methodOne(subjects)
</div>
```

Yet, if you insist on generating the HTML yourself, your better use `System.Web.Mvc.TagBuilder`:

> Contains classes and properties that are used to create HTML elements.
>   This class is used to write helpers, such as those found in the
>   System.Web.Helpers namespace.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tagbuilder%28v=vs.111%29.aspx).

Comment: If you genuinely have a need to generate HTML directly, this is indeed a better way to go.  I don't think the OP has that need, though.

Comment: The OP is using `StringBuilder` to 'Generate HTML directly'.

Comment: Yes, I know that.  Doesn't mean he has to.